# Why are my textboxes not updated with results from query

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

Self teaching myself PHP using problems at end of chapters of the book I'm using to learn how to apply the methods for each chapter. Created a html page that accepts user input of a car id, clicks a button and the information for that car is displayed in textboxes. I've searched a lot of documentation, SO and the web and could not find the method I'm looking for based on my current learning barometer. Would using php explode() method work or does the ajax/json do better job?

When I click search nothing is being populated in the text boxes so if someone can teach me what I'm doing wrong and where I need to fix my code that would be super great. Thanks!

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "car_search_db";
$user = "pontiac";
$password = "Race_Day!";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host",$user,$password);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include ('error.php');
    exit();
}   

$car_ID = isset($_GET['car_ID']) ? $_POST['car_ID'] : '';
if($car_ID == "")
    die("Invalid input");

$query = 'SELECT carID, make, model, year FROM fastCars
          WHERE carID = :car_ID';         
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':car_ID', $car_ID); 
$statement->execute();
$cars = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($cars);
echo $json;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Fast Car Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function queryCars() {
    //get user input
    var id = document.getElementById('car_ID').value;

    //create a query string
    var queryString = "?car_ID=" + car_ID;

    //create XMLHTTP Request
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }catch(e) {
        //IE Browsers
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXobjectect("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXobjectect("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Browser not compatible");
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
    //create ajax function that processes server response
     ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            var object = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById('car_id').value = object[0].car_ID;
            document.getElementById('make').value = object[1].make;
            document.getElementById('model').value = object[2].model;
            document.getElementById('year').value = object[3].year;         

        }
    };
            //execute the query
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "car_search.php" + queryString, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
}


</script> 
<header><h1>Fast Car Lookup - Search & Split</h1></header>
<br>
<h2>Search for a car info by ID</h2>
<br>
<form action="car_search.php" method="get">
<label>StudentID:</label>
<input type="text" id="id" name="car_ID">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button"  onclick="queryCars();" value="Search" id="get_info">

<h2>information will be displayed in the textboxes below for the car ID chosen:</h2>
<br>

<table id="outuput">
<tr>
    <td><label>Car ID:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="car_ID" value="" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Make:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="make" value="" readonly></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><label>Model:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="model" value="" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Year:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="" value="" readonly></td>
</tr>
<br>
</table>
</form>
<a href="index.htm">Back to first page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"mysql:dbname=$dbname; host=$host"` there shouldn't be any spaces in there. Do `"mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host"` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: You also have inputs outside your form which could also be an issue here.

Comment: Those were copy/paste errors to here. I am not getting any errors from the ide which is why Im confused why nothing is returned at all

Comment: No errors because you didn't check for them. This http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about the unassigned variable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Made changes to the php that initializes and GET input. Other than those few errors is the code logically ordered in that it should produce car information in the textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

you are binding the wrong variable here:

```
$statement->bindValue(':car_ID', $student_ID);
```

should be

```
$statement->bindValue(':car_ID', $car_ID);
```

also you are using post in your php but the car id is in the query string - should be using GET in the php.